# Extraction queries with variable last part of the search term

Tags: sql-server, extract

I have a problem with an extraction query.

I want to extract all records that begin with exactly one name.

The problem:

- Not always the end of the name is this extension;
- When they are present, they have no fixed length.

Example:

TabNames

```
id | Name

1 | Mike
2 | Mike Nell-1
3 | Mike-2
4 | Robert-1
5 | Mike Rio-NN
6 | Mike-Orio-2
.....
```

Name searched for: 'Mike'

Desired outcome:

```
Mike, Mike-2
```

If interested, I use SQL Server.

How can I do?

Comment: Why Mik resolves to Mike, Mike-2? Why did it not also resolve to Mike Nell -1 etc.

Comment: You're right Priyanshi Gel!
It was my mistake. The sample name is 'Mike'

Comment: This is a forum for programming questions.   To make this a programming question, you would have to fully define the rules for how to get your desired outcome.   Then we could help you with the programming.   Right now, this is a "What should my business rules be?" question, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with FOR XML.  You will have update the Table Names, Columns Names and Where Statement in both select statements.  This is a variation of this [Concatenation Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ', '+ T1.Name  AS [text()]
            FROM dbo.TabNames T1
            WHERE T1.Name LIKE 'Mike%'
            ORDER BY T1.Name
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 3, 8000) AS Names
FROM
    dbo.TabNames T2
WHERE
    T2.Name LIKE 'Mike%'
```